# changing ssl cert from single domain to wildcard and not getting browser warnings

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, heartbleed-bug

We are going to need to start supporting multiple subdomains soon (de. fr. etc) so will need to change to a wildcard certificate. This is also good timing with the heartbleed bug.

To change to a wildcard cert I will need to create a new CSR, then when I use this new certificate I am worried that users will be shown warnings in there browsers.

Is there a way to avoid this or have I misunderstood the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there will be no error if you turn your domain validated SSL certificate to WildCard SSL certificate, however you need to adjust domain name with new CSR such as for the WildCard SSL certificate, you need to use domain name in the format *.domainname.com

Wish you good luck! Cheers!